# Postgres Event Trigger on User Login / Logoff (Session starts and ends)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am working with event triggers and can log actions like creating tables:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION UpdateTables() returns event_trigger as $$
begin 
  -- do stuff
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';


create event trigger UpdateTables
   on ddl_command_end
   when tag in ( 'create table', 'alter table', 'drop table' )
   execute procedure UpdateTables();
```

Can you create an event trigger that executes whenever a user connects (session starts) and user disconnects (session ends).

I am running PostgreSql 9.6beta4.

Comment: No, that's not possible

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name seeing that event triggers get more functionality with each new release (e.g. added table_rewrite) event, do you think something could be possible in the future release?

Comment: You need to ask that question on one of the [mailing lists](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) (-general is a good place to start). But I have not seen [any mentioning](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Todo) of that. If you need it, consider sponsoring it